# http to https redirect on applicationwide scale

Tags: c#, asp.net

In our websolution if our environmentmode is set to production we want to redirect the user to a secure connection if the connection is insecure.

If possible I would really like to avoid having to call for this check on every page as there are hundreds of pages.

Is there anyway to accomplish this in global.asax? Or any other applicationwide solution?

I've tried the following:

```
if (SettingsHandler.EnvironmentMode == EnvironmentModes.Production)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://<obscured>");
    }
}
```

on the begin_request event.

It managed to detect if the connection is secure or not but the redirect fails and I get to a generic "the page could not be displayed" error page. The url doesn't translate in the clientbrowser either it just stays on the startpage, it's like the response is rendered corrupt or the server for some reason refuse to deliver it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SOLVED:
See my last comment in the accepted answer as to why I accepted it.

Comment: Sounds funny, can you put Fiddler on and see whether the server returns the 302 redirect header? Also maybe Response.End after your redirect.

Comment: @danswain the server didn't return anything before I managed to fix it. It was a clientside error that got displayed that the page could not be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this via IIS. This page shows how: http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

Alternativly you could use the global.asax - simply put your code in the Application_BeginRequest event inside global.asax.

BTW I tested this code and it caused any request to my site to redirect to google over ssl - I suspect your redirect might be in a try catch. If so remember to use the syntax:

```
Response.Redirect("site",true);
```

Here is the code that worked for me:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace repeater
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com");
        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

See if simplifying it to that works for you?

Comment: If you bothered to read my question you would see that your later solution is exactly what I tried. Thanks though I'll read up on the link you posted.

Comment: hmm, I'm interested in knowing why you get an error - you don't have it in a try catch do you?

Comment: it doesn't throw an error, the page is just not displayed/delivered with that redirect in it.

Comment: Oh and also, the solution in the link you posted, would that be searchengine friendly? It's very important that the redirects are seo and if the response is a 403 i don't think google will like it much.

Comment: @Jonas and if you had bothered retrieving the actual error message and posting that information. The chances are that you could get help with your actual problem. Iif it's the standard ASP.NET error message you refer to then it's written in the error page how to retrieve the actual error message

Comment: @Jonas why do you think a redirect would be a 403 (Unauthorized)?

Comment: Ok, What happens in dev if you remove the environment check? does the code get hit?

Comment: Hello, you indirectly solved my question so thank you! I used Response.Redirect instead of HttpContext.Current.Response and it worked. I have no idea why it shouldn't matter, but the important thing is that it works. Thanks hehe.

Comment: @Rune FS there ISNT an error message, the application never threw and exception it wasn't an asp error the page just didn't get delivered. Anyway it's solved, I don't know why the solution worked but it did (read above comment). And as to 403 unauthorized I was talking about the link he posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [iis url rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) module.

Just add the following to your web.config in the `<system.webServer>` section.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```